# Python dictionary converts single slash to double slash

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to send data using requests trying to send the payload from my side which requires date to be formatted like "\/Date(1532010600000)\/"

I am trying to make a custom payload which is to be sent using requests:

```
payload = {
        "GW_MeetingID": "1231324654654",
        "AltID": "This is ALT ID",
        "MeetingSubject": company,
        "MeetingComment": "",
        "RoomID": "xxxxx",
        "TimeZoneId": "Dateline Standard Time",
        "Organizer": organiser,
        "Start": "\\/Date(1532010600000)\\/"
    }
```

here the key should be "\/Date(1532010600000)\/" rather than "\\", using extra "\" as escape character. When i am trying to print this payload, it is showing value of start keys with "\\" which the api I am trying to send response to, doesn't accept. It only accepts 'Start' key as "\/Date(1532010600000)\/"

The solution that I have tried are using .encode('utf-8') and then decoding it using .decode('unicode_escape'). But still the dictionary had same response with "\\"

How can I make this payload to contain "\" in Start key?

```
import json
import requests


payload = {
        "GW_MeetingID": "1231324654654",
        "AltID": "This is ALT ID",
        "MeetingSubject": company,
        "MeetingComment": "",
        "RoomID": "e3e63148-5e4f-426e-98de-dec1687c9930",
        "TimeZoneId": "Dateline Standard Time",
        "Organizer": organiser,
        "Start": "\\/Date(1532010600000)\\/"
    }
print (payload)
# print (json.dumps(payload))
# a = (ast.literal_eval(payload))
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print (r.text)
```

Comment: how do you print the dict? because the actual value is `\/`. Try `print(payload["Start"])`

Comment: try print (payload). payload["Start"] does show correct value. I have added more to question 
I am trying to send the whole payload using requests.

Comment: try `print(payload["Start"])` not `print(payload)`

Comment: Try this `"Start": r"\/Date(1532010600000)\/"`, then you will send what you wrote

Comment: yes, but why the difference?
json.dumps(payload) is what I am sending and it is sending "//"
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

Comment: @rolandas I have already tried raw string, doesn't work

Comment: Do you have any error message? I had similar issue, I did like `to_json = json.dump(data)` and then `from_json = json.loads(to_json)` and then sending that data `from_json` and using raw string where it needs to be used to skip all the `\\`. Have you tried that? :)

Comment: I did, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't have an error message, because I am just trying to send this data which the server is not accepting as it is sending "\\". I was wondering why it is doing so?

Comment: You should get some error message, mostly REST APIs are providing error code if something is wrong. Try to do `r.status_code` and `r.content` and you should get the details. Atleast I think that they should provide details as they are requiring that specific field to be in specific format so I asume that they are prepared for those who are not sending correct data.

Comment: And how are you shore that they are not accepting that value if you don't see any error message?

Comment: well, they are displaying server error

Comment: But how you are sure that exactly because of this `"Start": "\\/Date(1532010600000)\\/"` you are getting server error?

Comment: I tried sending just the other parameters, i received accurate response(Same as curl).
then I added "Start" key, I started having this error (in curl i was sending single slash, I didn't have the error).

Comment: hmm, have you tried instead of `r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)` use `r = requests.post(url, json=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)` ?

Comment: yes, did that. Didn't work